# Extract Perfmon data from SQL

Tags: sql, perfmon

I typically log all of my perfmon data to a sql database.  Someone in the office requested that I pull out the data and put it back into a perfmon binary file (a .blg file).  Reasons for this is so that it's more portable for others to view without having to add in a datasource to their machine.  I did some searching and haven't found any methods to do this.  Is it possible?

Comment: I'm going to guess and say that a .blg file is a Microsoft proprietary format and it is not published, so you won't be able to create one yourself unless you want to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? ("SQL" is not the name of a DBMS product - it's a **query language** used by all relational databases)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. SQL database could be used as source for relog.exe.
Use following syntax for relog.exe to get data from SQL database:

*relog.exe SQL:(your_DSN_name_here)!(your_perfmon_preset_name_here) -b "start_date" -e "end_date" -f bin -o (your_blg_file_name_here)*

In my case:

*relog.exe SQL:PMDWH!JUMP01_System_Overview -b "02.03.2015 08:00:00AM" -e "02.03.2015 09:00:00AM" -f bin -o C:\Temp\SQLlogfile.blg*